# Need suggestion for encryption/decryption of MS word file

Tags: ms-word, aes

After I create a MS word doc I need to put it in server but I don't want anybody to see it. I need my own program to decrypt and see it. For this I am planning to use AES for encryption. Is it true that any programmer who has a AES dycryption program can decrypt it? Or is there anything specific extra I can add to my program to make it accessible to me only?

Answer (score 0):

---

## Protecting Word Documents

---

For Microsoft Word documents (Word 2000 and newer), you can choose a higher level of security when saving a file. Rather than simply clicking "Save", click File, then Save As and follow these steps:

1. Click on Tools in the upper right corner of the file save dialog box
2. Click on Security Options
3. The Security Options box provides a variety of options:

   - You can enter a password in the box next to Password to open if you wish the file to be completely inaccessible without the password
   - In Word 2002 and 2003, you can click on the Advanced button next to the password box to choose a higher level of encryption that is even harder to break into
   - You can enter a password in the box next to Password to modify if it is OK for others to open the file, but you want to restrict who can make changes to the file
4. The bottom of the Security Options box also provides some choices to protect the privacy of the document:

   - Remove personal information from file properties on save
   - Warn before printing, saving or sending a file that contains tracked changes or comments
   - Store random number to improve merge accuracy
   - Make hidden markup visible when opening or saving
5. Click on OK to close the Security Options box
6. Select a name for your file and click Save

---

[More Information](http://netsecurity.about.com/od/frequentlyaskedquestions/f/faq_encryptms.htm)

---